# Can someone help me with this double integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, area, differential, angle

can someone solve this double integral step-by-step please???!!! It is from a differential solid angle problem: 
$$\int_{z=c}^{a+b}\int_{y=-b}^{b}\frac{x(dy)(dz)}{(x^2 + (2-y)^2 + (3.45-z)^2)^(3/2)] - [3*(x^2 + (2-y)^2 + (3.45-z)^2]}$$
(it is 3/2 squared!)

Thanks!!!

Comment: 1. Use Mathjax 2. Write your try

Comment: So you take $x$ constant?

Comment: That's the problem, I didn't try because I don't have any idea of how to solve it.

Comment: No, I think x is a variable

Answer (score 2):

Observe that
$$ \int \frac{1}{(t^2 + b)^{3/2}} \,\mathrm dt = \frac{t}{b\sqrt{b+t^2}} + \mathrm C
$$
using the substitution $t = \sqrt{b} \tan s$ and $\mathrm dt = \sqrt{b} (\sec s)^2\,\mathrm ds$.

Repeative application of the above identity to the integrand gives you the result.